# Extending a page in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am working on a custom page in Silverstripe and although this is absolutely basic, I still can't get it done.

I created the FundraisingPage (code below) and set a new page to be a FundraisingPage. I then included the array for the fields and the getCMSFields. I re-built the database and flushed the cache but it doesn't show me the fields in the backend.

Thank you for your help.
Alex

```
<?php
 class FundraisingPage extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        'fr_video_url' => 'Text',
        'fr_form_url' => 'Text',
        'fr_meter_url' => 'Text',
        'fr_meter_url_employers' => 'Text',
        'fr_meter_url_classes' => 'Text',
    );

     public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Links', new TextField('fr_video_url', 'Video URL'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Links', new TextField('fr_form_url', 'Form URL'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Links', new TextField('fr_meter_url', 'Meter URL'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Links', new TextField('fr_meter_url_employers','Meter URL by employer'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Links', new TextField('fr_meter_url_classes', 'Meter URL by classes'), 'Content');

        return $fields;
    }

 }


class FundraisingPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete ", 'Content'" at the end of each addFieldToTab. Since you have no Content-Field in the tab Links you cannot add the fields after "Content".

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Links', new TextField('fr_meter_url_classes', 'Meter URL by classes'));
```